# How to logout FBWebDialogs?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I develope app with facebook sdk 3.11. and i don't know how  to logout FBWebDialogs  .
my code:

```
- (void) logoutFacebook
{
    NSLog(@"Close session");
    [[FBSession activeSession]close];
    [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

        if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:@"facebook"]) {

            [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
}
```

but when i reopen share dialog , it alway use old account. 
How  to logout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you do not have FB connect active on your device, try this:

```
- (void) logoutFacebook
{
    NSLog(@"Close session");
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString *domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
}
```